# USA undergraduate seeking advice for PhD from Europe

Tags: phd, undergraduate, university, europe, chemistry

I am hoping someone reading this can help me in this area. I am an Applied Chemistry undergraduate and I want to earn my PhD, however ,the PhD programs in the US are very long  spanning about 5-7 years. My goal is to go straight from undergraduate to PhD. From what I am reading this is possible. I just need help with the process.

1. What do I do and where do I start?
2. Are the PhD programs in Europe competitive and do I need a certain
   GPA?
3. I am really seeking a PhD program where I can finish in 3 years
   without doing my Masters?
4. But how do I get in?
5. And what universities have PhD programs best for Chemistry that I
   can get into?
6. I just want to know where to start and what are the requirements so
   that I can proceed the application process. Any advice anyone?

Comment: Too many questions, and questions are too broad. A PhD is not an extended undergrad degree.

Comment: Also ‘Europe’ isn’t one place, some Americans might be surprised to know

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/135841) might be relevant to you. There you can also see that in many European countries you need a Masters degree to start a PhD. That's essentially the reasons why PhDs there tend to be shorter.

Comment: See the linked question for #1, 2, and 4. #3 is addressed by the preceeding comment. And #5-6 are not the kind of questions we can take here. Good luck.